# Floating point error when dividing one small range by another small range

Tags: floating-point

When i have two (small) numbers min and max and try to get a value between 0 and 1 using the following code, can i get values less than 0 or bigger than 1?

```
double min, max, min2, max2, mid, result;
// min2 < max2 is a subrange of min < max with min2 >= min and max2 <= max
// where max-min may be very small, which means max2-min2 will be very small as well.
mid = (min2+max2)/2.0;
result = (mid - min)/(max-min)
```

I had the problem, that i got values bigger than 1 when `min, max` were float while `min2, max2` were doubles.
Now i made them all `double` variables, but I am still not sure if floating point errors can produce wrong results.

Later i want to use the result to subdivide a number range by using

```
const int MAX=63;
double array[64];
int index = (int)(result*MAX);
array[index];
```

And want to get accurate indices even for small differences.

An example where i got the problems when mixing doubles and floats:

```
NUM_BINS = 64
min = -5.00958252
max = -5.00958014
min2 = -5.0095801960014716
max2 = -5.0095799398356107
mid = (max2+min2) / 2.0
mid - min = 2.4516127083984429e-06
(mid - min) / (max - min)) * (NUM_BINS - 1) = 64.781696632504463
```

Comment: Can you give a mathematical argument why `result` *shouldn't* be able to go over `1`, considering that you have not given any information about `min2` and `max2` relative to `min` and `max`?

Comment: max2 <= max and min2 >=min means max2-min2 <= max-min. The real question is about floating point arithmetics, where strange things can happen.

Comment: Added this as explicit comment to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming IEEE754 arithmetic, if min and max are close enough, then the difference is exact.

The average for calculating the mid point is not necessarily exact (division by 2 is exact assuming no underflow, but sum is not), but the following expressions are all true:

```
min2 <= mid
mid <= max2
```

`mid-min` will be exact (and thus `<= (max-min)`), so last inexact operation / will round to nearest floating-point value. Since exact value is <= 1, there is no reason for it to be rounded above 1.

Above relations still hold if the compiler decided to use excess precision. What could happen when you used mixed precision, I don't well see... I'd be curious if you could exhibit the exact values (in hexadecimal format).

Comment: I added the values (no hex, they are just like i saved them when debugging) to the question.

Comment: Yes, the example was obviously wrong. It mixed float and double, which was causing the problem here. But I am not sure if using the same floating point type really solved the issue or if it may happen again with certain (smaller) values.

Comment: OK I see, rounding to lower precision broke the contract because `float(max2) < max2`, but if the contract min <= min2 <= max2 <= max is honoured, then mixed precision does not much matter, the result will be <= 1.

Comment: Okay. Then i accept your answer now. i just wanted to be sure, as I can now close a bug, where i was unsure if its really fixed.